# array.splice() function explanation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm fairly new with jQuery and I'm not sure what this splice function does.

Does it check that "My_adress" exists in the profilingArray and then removes it?, Or does it add it at position 1?

```
profilingArray.splice(jQuery.inArray('My_adress',profilingArray),1);
```

Ty very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using a jQuery function but the [standard javascript splice function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

`splice` is a convenient function used to add or remove items in arrays.

Here you're just removing one (`1`) item from the position of `'My_adress'` in `profilingArray`. So you're removing `'My_adress'` from the array.

Comment: I think OP is referring (partially) to the `jQuery.inArray` method, and is confused by its unintuitive name.

Answer (score 0):

It gets the `index` of the element in the `array`, and then removes `1` element starting at that `index`, meaning it removes the element. [Splice explained.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp)